# Format git log output with sed, awk, or the like

Tags: git, formatting, sed, awk

If I have output like this (from customized git log)

```
d1fd022 2011-09-21 17:02:26 -0400       Replace double quotes with single quotes.
7227fe4 2011-09-21 13:57:36 -0400       Add automatic CommandTFlush to mkdir/rm/touch/cd
```

How could you pipe it through `sed`, `awk` or similar to achieve this output?

```
d1fd022 2011-09-21 17:02       Replace double quotes with single quotes.
7227fe4 2011-09-21 13:57       Add automatic CommandTFlush to mkdir/rm/touch/cd
```

Here the only difference is that seconds and timezone are cut out from the date. Unfortunately, git doesn't seem to support custom date formats and I'm not good with the likes of `sed`, so need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `cut` (POSIX):

```
[guest@pawel] ~ $ cut -c 1-24,34- foo.txt  
d1fd022 2011-09-21 17:02       Replace double quotes with single quotes.
7227fe4 2011-09-21 13:57       Add automatic CommandTFlush to mkdir/rm/touch/cd
```

Answer (score 1):

awk version:

```
awk -F':[0-9][0-9] | ' '{$4=""}1' inputFile
```

**test:**

```
kent$  echo "d1fd022 2011-09-21 17:02:26 -0400       Replace double quotes with single quotes.
7227fe4 2011-09-21 13:57:36 -0400       Add automatic CommandTFlush to mkdir/rm/touch/cd"|awk -F':[0-9][0-9] | ' '{$4=""}1'

d1fd022 2011-09-21 17:02        Replace double quotes with single quotes.
7227fe4 2011-09-21 13:57        Add automatic CommandTFlush to mkdir/rm/touch/cd
```

Comment: Hm weird, running this command (`git mine | awk -F':[0-9][0-9] | ' '{$4=""}1'`) returns the same output as `git mine`. (`git mine` is my git alias that returns git log in the given format). Maybe something needs to be escaped in zsh?

Comment: here is zsh as well. ;) try the codes under my "test" block : echo "..."|awk -F...  what output do you get?

Comment: I decided to settle on the `cut` solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/:[^:]* -[^     ]*//' infile
```

Fixed (it's not a space, it's a tab).

Comment: This regex also removes the first word of the commit message.

Comment: Got it, you need to enter a literal tab: `sed 's/:[^:]* -[^Ctrl+V<TAB>]*//' infile` or use this syntax: `sed 's/:[^:]* -[^\t]*//' infile` if your sed implementation supports it (GNU sed, for example).

Comment: This still seems to break output when piping into sed: `d1fd022 2011-09-21 17:02lace double quotes with single quotes.`, `7227fe4 2011-09-21 13:57Add automatic CommandTFlush to mkdir/rm/touch/cd commands.` (I tried both suggested versions, and I'm on OS X)

Comment: OK, you seem not to inserting the literal tab correctly, you need to type Control-V and then the TAB character of your keyboard here: `sed 's/:[^:]* -[^*here you need to type Control-V and then TAB*]*//' infile`.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah it's a little convoluted, probably due to the chars git is using in its log output. : /